# Rust Streams: How to transform a TryStream<Ok = Vec<Item>, Error = MyErrorType>> into TryStream<Ok = Item, Error = MyErrorType>

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, stream

I'm playing around with streams in Rust using the `futures-util` crate.

I'm creating a stream that requests a new page from a paginated API on each step.
The item of each page is basically a Vector. And as it might be obvious, each call to the server to request a new page might fail.

Instead of returning a Stream of vectors I would like to return a stream of items that yields an error (and therefore closes the stream) when trying to fetch an item from a page that failed.

Here is my current function:

```rust
    pub fn search(
        &self,
        query: Query,
    ) -> impl TryStream<Ok = Vec<Item>, Error = MyError> {
        let initial_state = (query, None);
        stream::try_unfold(initial_state, |(query, page_token)| async move {
            let (items, next_page_token) = fetch_page(&query, page_token).await?;
            if items.len() <= 0 {
                Ok(None)
            } else {
                Ok(Some((items, (query, next_page_token))))
            }
        })
    }
```

I would like to modify it so the return type is `impl TryStream<Ok = Item, Error = MyError>`

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`try_flatten()`](https://docs.rs/futures-util/latest/futures_util/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_flatten), however it requires every the inner stream to be a `TryStream` too so you need to map every item:

```rust
use futures_util::stream::TryStreamExt;

pub fn search(query: Query) -> impl TryStream<Ok = Item, Error = MyError> {
    let initial_state = (query, None);
    stream::try_unfold(initial_state, |(query, page_token)| async move {
        let (items, next_page_token) = fetch_page(&query, page_token).await?;
        if items.len() <= 0 {
            Ok(None)
        } else {
            Ok(Some((items, (query, next_page_token))))
        }
    })
    .map_ok(|items| stream::iter(items.into_iter().map(|item| Ok(item))))
    .try_flatten()
}
```

Note however that it is better to return `impl Stream<Item = Result<Item, MyError>>` than `impl TryStream`, because `impl Stream` will automatically implement `TryStream` too but the opposite is not true.

Comment: Thank you it worked! The only thing is that then the compiler complains because it can't infer the return type of the closure inside `try_unfold` so I have to inline it somewhere like in the first branch of the if`Ok::<_, MyError>(None)`

Comment: @JasterV Well it didn't complain for me (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=567ad4bb5dcd07e6ef7439d39619923a), interested it complained for you.